# Unable to find sharing info Win8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, share, contract, charms-bar

I'm creating a Windows 8 app that should be using the Share contract that is the sharing source, but the problem is that it keeps on waiting for share info from the app but I can't manage to find out why it's still waiting...
The only code I inserted was  :

```
public void InitializeShare()
    {
        _shareManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        _shareManager.DataRequested += OnShareDataRequested;
    }

    private void OnShareDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
            DataRequest request = args.Request;
            request.Data.Properties.Title = "blablabla";
            request.Data.Properties.Description = "blablabla";
            request.Data.SetText("blablabla");
        }
    }
```

This is what I get...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by rebooting my machine.